# Flutter multiple itemCount?

Tags: flutter

I have three JSON request in 1 screen the code is working fine but sometimes 2 second it show an error says:

*Exception has occurred.

NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null

Tried calling: [ ] ( 0 ) )*

and then back to normal again it a flicker a red screen error in just 2 seconds.

```
String url1 = "https://api-1.php"; 
    var response1 = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(url1), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

data1 = jsonDecode(response1.body);

.......

String url2 = "https://api-2.php"; 
    var response2 = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(url2), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

data2 = jsonDecode(response2.body);

.......

String url3 = "https://api-3.php"; 
    var response2 = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(url3), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

data3 = jsonDecode(response3.body);

//*******How to add the data2 and data3 in itemCount?******//
itemCount: data1 == null ? 0 : data1.length,
```

Comment: `itemCount: data1 == null ? 0 : data.length`
maybe it should be `data1.length`

Comment: typo I corrected how can I add data2 and data3?

Comment: easiest way is to create the method say `int getCount(List list)=> list == null ? 0 : data.length;` and then `itemCount:getCount(data1)+getCount(data2)+getCount(data3)`

Comment: no problem, say if something wrong!

Comment: I got an error here brother --->   Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length) ::::::::::::::> int getCount(List list)=> list == null ? 0 : data.length;

Comment: please check updated comment, should be list.length

Comment: Exception has occurred.
RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1) by the way the data1 and data2 are NOT a list bro